# Finding a function of f that satisfies the derivative.

Tags: calculus

Problem: Find one function of $f$ that satisfies $f’(x) = 4x^2 - 2x$.

Do I simply go backwards and find the anti derivative? 
Here’s what I think may be the antiderivative:
$1.33x^3 - x^2$

Comment: You shouldn't write $\frac43$ as $1.33$, but otherwise you're right.

Answer (score 3):

Yes indeed, you have the right idea.

Probably better to write $\frac43$ instead of $1.33$ since the former is exact but the latter is only an approximation.

Also, don't forget that you could also include any constant term you want, since it would vanish when you take its derivative.